# How does YOLO split images into grid cells?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to learn object detection models and strategies they use but I cant get my head around understanding how Yolo or SSD does it using convolutional neural networks. Can anybody give some insight ? How do they structure CNN's ? It would be wonderful if code(Python) could be provided.